# Why does the control flow does not follow the code execution order?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying out the following example in nodejs

```
"use strict";

const 
  fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('target.txt',function(err, data){
if (err) { throw err;
}
  console.log(data.toString())

})

fs.writeFile('target.txt','writing some content',function(err){
  if(err)
    throw err;
console.log("file saved")
})
```

As per the code, I read the file, print its content. Then I write some content in the same file and print the text file saved in the console. But my output is

```
file saved
writing some content
```

The `writeFile` function is executed first rather than the `readFile`. Why does this happen and how can this be avoided?

Comment: I know node.js do have auto complete, but please use `;`, it will prevent how so much error (in other cases that this one).

Answer (score 5):

The functions you pass as the second argument to those two functions are *callbacks*. They are executed when the operation is completed - and execution order is not guaranteed.

To guarantee that the write occurrs after the read is complete, place the code to trigger a write into the callback of the `readFile` method.

```
"use strict";

const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('target.txt', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data.toString());

    fs.writeFile('target.txt', 'writing some content', function(err) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("file saved")
    });
});
```